# Service Timer Ticking with AutoEnabled False

Tags: c#, service, timer

I have created a Windows Service that is meant to not be automatically re-enabled

I have created the timer as such

```
private Timer timer1 = null;


timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.Interval = 6000;
timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.AutoReset = false;
```

Then the timer tick method

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsServerConnected(db.Connectionstring))
        {
        //Error Handling
        timer1.Interval = 300000;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(cfg.CSVPath))
            {
                //error handling
                timer1.Interval = 300000;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Interval = 60000;
                //Code
            }

        }
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

The timer will tick after 6 seconds as it is meant to and then gets to the timer1.Interval = 60000;

section after it encounters no errors.

However, the code in the comment takes more than a minute to run. After a minute, even though the code is still running in Timer1_Tick, the event gets fired again even though i shouldn't have started the timer back up.

Can anyone see where i am going wrong? Does setting the interval automatically start the timer back up? Therefore i dont need Timer1.Start() at the end of my code, but rather set the interval after all of my code is finished? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have tried stopping the timer

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
timer1.Stop();
```

Before setting the interval, however this too is causing multiple ticks

Comment: `timer1.Interval = 60000` this is 60 seconds, not 6 seconds. `timer1.Interval = 300000;` this is 300 seconds (five minutes) actually

Comment: Hi

Yes, so the timer runs after 6 seconds, if there is an error sets the interval to 5 minutes and if not it sets the interval to 60 seconds

The issue is the 6 second timer ticks successfully, but then the 60 second tick happens whilst the 6 second tick is still running

I need it to not run two ticks together, which i thought id achieved by putting auto reset to false, but apparently not :-(

Comment: please try to stop the timer at the beginning of `timer1_Tick`, do your stuff, set interval and then start the timer like you does. Seems that only `timer.Stop()` is missing in your sample

Comment: Unfortunately even with stopping the timer it seems to still tick multiple times